# What is going on with the symbol in the weight here?

Tags: vocabulary, new-latin, abbreviations, numbers, measurements

So [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penates_apud_Devisas_in_Belgio_Nostro_Effossi_Anno_1714_Tab_IV.jpg) is an image from [William Musgrave's account of the Southbroom Hoard](https://archive.org/details/b30538014_0001/page/122/mode/2up?view=theater) discovered outside Devizes, Wiltshire, in England in 1714. They seem to be some local's cache hidden away around the reign of Severus Alexander and a mix of Roman (Venus, Bacchus, &c.), Gallo-Roman (Sucellus), and Romanized Celtic ("Mars", "Vulcan", &c.) gods. The British Museum got 6 of the 19ish pieces in 1811 and the rest are lost and/or forgotten about in some aristocrat's storage rooms.

The important bit for this forum: What's going on with the weights (*Pondo*) here? Obviously the lengths (*Long*) are written in Latin (*Uncias*) but actually talking about English inches. Obviously the dotted *w* is just an unhelpful version of *iv*. Presumably these small figurines were weighed in ounces (also, unhelpfully, *uncias*). **Is that weird cursive** Z **before most of the weights just an abbreviation for ounces? a stylized number? or something completely different?**

**Bonus points for whatever the *ss* is really talking about**. From context, I'd guess it's some Latin equivalent to *even* or *~.0* but it could be something completely different.

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain enough to make this an answer, but I suspect it's ℨ, a symbol for drams (fractions of an ounce).

Comment: If the density makes any difference, the British Museum says the remaining copies are copper alloy and 5-10 cm tall. A 4 inch tall (10 cm) copper statue shouldn't only weigh 4/16 oz. (7 grams), should it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to Draconis's helpful comment above, I was able to find that the main thing I was looking for was [℥](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%84%A5), which—yeah—[is a weird old apothecary symbol for ounces](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%84%A5). I'll still give a tick mark and thanks to anyone who repeats that and can help explain what the long S  ⟨*ſſ*⟩s are doing up there.